# is there a way to convert access reports to crystal reports?

Tags: c#, ms-access, crystal-reports

The firm is starting to code it's apps from Access to C#.

There are a lot of reports in Access that need to be migrated to Crystal reports.

Is there a way to somehow convert those access reports and use them in c# and crystal reports?

Comment: I suppose there is no simple way

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Keep in mid that Access reports can contain VBA code. I don't believe that crystal reports allows macro or VBA code inside of a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, sorry. We are working with Crystal Reports and you can't migrate them. They are sometimes very complex.